# Getting and creating stored access policy on a container results in a 404, resource not found

Tags: azure-storage

I have a Gen2 Azure storage account and try to create a stored access policy on a container using Powershell. I am signed into the account and the relevant subscription is selected. I save the context in a variable for further use by the following statements.

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscriptionid>"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "MyStorageAccount" -UseConnectedAccount
```

Creating a stored access policy failed so I added one manually through the portal and tried to get a list of the policies:

`Get-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy -Container "MyContainer" -Context $context`

This resulted in an error `Get-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy: The specified resource does not exist.`, the same error that the "New-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy" command yielded. Adding the name of the existing policy with the `-Policy` parameter did not change the outcome, neither did changing the access level on the container.

I think I can also rule out typos as `Get-AzStorageContainer "MyContainer" -Context $context` gives me the details of the container as expected.

I am unclear as to what resource it is that does not exists, as the container clearly exists and it also contains at least one stored access policy. Can the container stored access policy command not be used on a Gen2 storage account or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Get/New-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy` isn't supported by Oauth. You can find all operations supported by Oauth https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftstorage.

As a workaround, you can use connection string to do this:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscriptionid>"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString "<Connection string>"
Get-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy -Container "<Container Name>" -Context $context
```

Same issue in Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10391.